# Chebyshev-like lower bound

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Using the well-known [Chebyshev's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality) we can upper-bound the tail of the distribution of a random variable $X$ using its variance $\sigma^2_X$ moment as follows:

$$P(|X-\mu_X|\geq k\sigma_X)\leq 1/k^2$$

Obviously, only case when $k>1$ is useful.

I am wondering if there exists a moment-based lower bound which I can use to lower-bound

$$P(X\geq\mu_X+k\sigma_X)$$

where $0<k<1$.  Unfortunately nothing except for the moments is known about $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*A negative result, sorry about that...*

Assume that $X$ is centered Bernoulli, that is, that $P[X=x]=1-x$ and $P[X=x-1]=x$ for some $x$ in $(\frac12,1)$, and let $A_k=[X\geqslant\mu_X+k\sigma_X]$. Then $\mu_X=0$ and $\sigma_X^2=x(1-x)$. Furthermore, $x\gt\frac12$ hence $x\gt\sqrt{x(1-x)}$ and one sees that, for every $k$ in $(0,1)$, $x\gt\mu_X+k\sigma_X$. Thus $A_k=[X=x]$, which implies $P[A_k]=1-x$. This can be as close to $0$ as one wants hence no general lower bound of $P[A_k]$ can hold.

Comment: A negative result is still a result.  Thank you for the enlightening explanation!